# UI-Grid 3.0 E2E protractor testing

Tags: protractor, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to perform a select row on my E2E test so that I can see if one of my buttons is working when a row is selected.  My test gets to the page but when I try to selectRow it gives me an error. Currently test looks like this.

```
var GridTestUtils = require('./gridTestUtils.spec.js');

describe('Tests', function() {
    it('should switch to clients and add a client', function() {
        expect(element(by.id('table')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
        expect(element(by.id('sideNavLink')).getAttribute('class')).toEqual('active');
        GridTestUtils.expectRowCount('table', 2);
        element(by.id('addSubNavLink')).click();
        expect(element(by.model('modalData.name')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
        element(by.model('modalData.name')).sendKeys('Protractor Test Client');
        element(by.id('clientSubmit')).click();
        //GridTestUtils.expectRowCount('table', 3);
        GridTestUtils.selectRow('table', 3);
        element(by.id('deleteButton')).click();
    });
});
```

When I run protractor I get this error:

```
Message:
 NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.repeater((rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index").row("3")"
```

If there is another way to highlight a row, I haven't found it yet, but I've been going through the gridTestUtils.spec.js and that was the first one I'd found.

Answer (score 0):

Grid rows and columns are using zero-based index.

This is not directly documented, but is apparent when you compare your error with implementation in `gridTestUtils.spec.js`, the row parameter is passed to [repeater](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater).row() locator which is zero based as per examples.

So if your grid has 3 rows

`GridTestUtils.expectRowCount('table', 3);`

you can select the last row by

`GridTestUtils.selectRow('table', 2);`